# How would the english sentence structure "may you ___", kind of like something you might hear in a toast

Tags: grammar, translation

I've been trying to figure this out to no avail. In the instance of a toast you might hear someone say something like the Irish toast "may you be in heaven before the devil knows you're dead." The "may you ___" construction.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

We often say ～ますように！ in many situations, but *in a toast*, we commonly say 「～～を願って、乾杯！」 or 「～～を祈って、乾杯！」「～～をお祈りして、乾杯！」

Examples:

> 「〇〇社のますますの発展を願って、乾杯！」
>   「〇〇家のますますの繁栄を祈って、乾杯！」
>   「〇〇さんの今後のご活躍とご健勝をお祈りして、乾杯！」

... We usually use these phrases in formal parties.